# How to localize LoginPath in ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-localization

I use `CookieAuthentication` in ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1 and I have to set the `LoginPath` while configuring in the `Startup.cs`.

I have this so far:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication("CookieAuthentication")
            .AddCookie("CookieAuthentication", config =>
            {
                config.Cookie.Name = "UserLoginCookie";
                config.LoginPath = "/connexion"; 
                config.SlidingExpiration = true;
                config.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
            });

    ...
}
```

But I would like now to be able to **localize** the `LoginPath` but I can't figure out how.

My goal is to call different Url according to the current culture. For example `/connexion` if the culture is French and `/connect` if it's English.

Any ideas how to achieve this??

Thank you!

Comment: You can redirect with different culture in your login view.Or you can [localize your login view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1).Or you can use [CookieAuthenticationEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57601559/dynamic-cookie-authentication-loginpath-asp-net-core-2) to change redirectUrl.

Comment: I could solve the problem thanks to your last link. Thank you!